# REGEXP_REPLACE for exact regex pattern, not working

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I'm trying to match an exact pattern to do some data cleanup for ISSN's using the code below:

```
select case when REGEXP_REPLACE('1234-5678 ÿþT(zlsd?k+j''fh{l}x[a]j).,~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?`"\;''/-',  '([0-9]{4}[\-]?[Xx0-9]{4})(.*)', '$1') not similar to '[0-9]{4}[\-]?[Xx0-9]{4}' then 'NOT' else 'YES' end
```

The pattern I want match any 8 digit group with a possible dash in the middle and possible X at the end.

The code above works for most cases, but if capture group 1 is the following example: `123456789` then it also returns positive because it matches the first 8 digits, and I don't want it to.

I tried surrounding capture group 1 with `^...$` but that doesn't work either.

So I would like to match exactly these examples and similar ones:

```
1234-5678 
1234-567X 
12345678 
1234567X
```

BUT NOT THESE (and similar):

```
1234567899
1234567899x
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `^([0-9]{4}-?[Xx0-9]{4})([^0-9].*)?$`. Replace `[\-]?` with `-?` everywhere, BTW.

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you. I do need need it to recognize a possible space as well as a dash, so I did this: `^([0-9]{4}[\\s|\-]?[Xx0-9]{4})([^0-9].*)?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^([0-9]{4}-?[Xx0-9]{4})([^0-9].*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gCGh3M/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]{4}-?[Xx0-9]{4})` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): four digits, an optional `-`, and then four `x` / `X` or digits
- `([^0-9].*)?` - an optional Capturing group 2: any char other than a digit and then any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.